# Hibernate newly created object merge fails

Tags: hibernate, session, merge, save

I am trying to implement a save changes /cancel changes screen.

I have one main hibernate session. When someone wants to edit an object I create a temporary session and merge the object from main session.

```
// To edit Object x with id id_x
Object a = mainSession.get(id_x);
Object b = tempSession.merge(a);

// Change object b with tempSession

// If save: mainSession.merge(b) and discard tempSession.
// If cancel: discard b and tempSession.

...
...

// If saveAll: mainSession.flush();
// If cancellAll: mainSession.rollback(), reload all objects.
```

This works with items that are already in the database. But when I want to apply the same logic with a newly created object tempSession.merge(a) fails.

```
Object d = new Object();
mainSession.save(d);
// To edit Object d with id id_d
Object a = mainSession.get(id_d);
Object b = tempSession.merge(a); // The application gets blocked/locked here.
```

I think tempSession.merge tries to load the object from database since tempSession doesn't have the object with id_d but since the object doesn't exist in the database or the table/row is locked it fails. Is there a way to create a copy of object d and attach it to tempSession and then re-attach it to mainSession? Or can you suggest alternative ways to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need this complicated setup with two sessions? In general you shouldn't use multiple session in the same thread simultaneously due to possible deadlocks.

There are many ways to achieve desired behaviour without using multiple sessions. For example, you can `detach()` loaded object from the session and merge it into the same session later. Or you can keep the object attached and call `refresh()` when you want to discard changes.

Comment: The user goes over a list of items. The user selects an item from the list and edits it. Then he/she Saves the changes or Cancels them. And later when he finishes editing all items he can choose Save All or Cancel All. For this functionality I should only update the database when the user clicks Save All. For "intermediate Save / Cancel" actions I have to create a copy of the object in case the user selects Cancel. The user can also edit the same item more than once (edit object A save it, edit object B save it and then re-edit A and save it).

Comment: If I call refresh I think the object gets the values from database again, then I will lose previous changes.

Comment: @exoz: If you need a copy of the object, it would be better to clone the object manually (perhaps using `Clobeable`) rather than rely on Hibernate to do it.

Comment: Ok I'll consider that meanwhile I am still curios about this scenario. I create an object and save it in a Hibernate session and get the id of the object. Using the generated id I want to retrieve it from another Hibernate session but the application gets locked. Is there a way to remove the lock on the table when I execute a save?